# How to encrypt decrypted text by django-fernet-fields?

Tags: python, django, fernet

I am  using django-fernet-fields, and documentation says By default, django-fernet-fields uses your SECRET_KEY setting as the encryption key. my SECRET_KEY in django is the one created by django let say it is "XXXX".

my dectypted text is "gAAAAABfIrFwizr11ppteAXE3MOMItPDNfNkr5a4HcS3oiT7ih4Ln7y6TeCC5uXWPS3Yup_0s7whK3T44ndNlJRgc0Ii4_s3_A=="

when I try to encrypt it by using the code below

```
token = SECRET_KEY
f = Fernet(token)
d =f.decrypt(b"gAAAAABfIrFwizr11ppteAXE3MOMItPDNfNkr5a4HcS3oiT7ih4Ln7y6TeCC5uXWPS3Yup_0s7whK3T44ndNlJRgc0Ii4_s3_A==")
print(d)
```

it throws an error, error is **ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.**
how can i avoid this error?

Comment: You are trying to decrypt the secret key, but its not possible. You can decrypt only base-64 encoded bytes data

Comment: i am not decrypting  secret key. i am decrypting  a text with secret key. where secret key is the fernet token.